# Add default value on a function in Typescript 4.4+

Tags: typescript

I have tried this:

```
const test = ( a: number, b?: boolean = true ): number => {
    return b ? a : 0
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work.

I tried using an object as so:

```
const test = ({ a, b = true} : { a: number, b?: boolean }): number => {
    return b ? a : 0
}
```

But then I need to pass the parameters as an object, which makes it a bit cumbersome.

Do you know of a nicer solution?

Comment: Neither of those is actually arrow function syntax. `b?: number = 4` is fine as an optional parameter with a default value (although note that providing a default value _automatically_ makes the parameter optional).

Comment: "*Unfortunately, it does not work.*" well, `const = sum` is incorrect, should be `const sum =`. And the body of the function doesn't use the parameters. But if you change these [it does work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCuBbGBeGAKGBDAXDMSARgKYBOANDIQPx4GImmowAsMAlHUWTAN4BQMITFLEo8UmGwwAVBgCMMALRV2Abn4Bffv1CQQAG2IA6AyADm6BInTyADHfbsgA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply apply default directly ;)

```
const sum = ( a: number, b = 4 ): number {
    return price * (1 - discount);
}
```

you can also avoid explicit return type as it is inferred..

```
const sum = ( a: number, b = 4 ) {
    return price * (1 - discount);
}
```

... also notice there's a syntax mistake:
`const = sum`  should be `const sum =`

Comment: You should rarely if ever avoid the explicit return type - it can be inferred, sure, but if you're explicit it can be _checked_ (so you don't end up with an unexpected `Promise<T>` or `T | undefined` or whatever).

Comment: @jonrsharpe there might be a pesky eslint rule which requires you to provide explicit return type. I have such in my project :(

Comment: @captain-yossarian there are several _useful_ ESLint rules, e.g. [`@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-module-boundary-types.md) and [`@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md). Give the compiler the information it needs to help you (and everyone else), or you might as well not be using TS.

Comment: @jonrsharpe agreed. For example if the function did (through mistake) `return "" + a + b`  the the return type would be inferred correctly as a string but that's most definitely not what you wanted. And if the entire body of the function was `if (someCondition) return a + b;` it ends up as `number | undefined` where you might have wanted it to be just `number`.

Comment: oh, I was referring to this particular case, where the return type is unambiguous    
I'd also assert that in a good TS codebase *almost every* function return type is inferable correctly, 
exceptions are typically IO-funcs or un(correctly)typed 3rd party libs, 
and it's good practice to shrink, isolate, and explicitly type them

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't have such power in the project to add or remove eslint rules :D I can only obey them :D

Comment: Most functions' return types can be correctly inferred _if they're implemented correctly_, the point of providing the explicit type is so the compiler can help you spot (some of) the cases where they aren't.

Comment: @jonrsharpe agreed again. I recently saw a problem where through omission there was a missing implementation for one (technically unreachable) branch of code in a function. Which then freaked out everywhere because the type of the function used to be `X` now it was `X | undefined` and all callers threw an error. And some of their callers, too, since in the instances where the implementation was akin to `return doSomething(thisParticularValue)` and were also implicit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ale! I thought you needed to add the type on the not mandatory parameter, but on my case, where I needed a boolean it could infer it properly. But in other cases, where you can expect different incoming types, it's good to see that is possible by just doing `b: number = 4`. Thank you @jason-kleban for that tip!

Answer (score 0):

Your troubles are mostly in syntax.  Try this:

```
const sum = ( a: number, b: number = 4 ): number => {
    return a * (1 - b);
}

console.log(sum(5));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I like the fact that you add the type on the optional value.

Answer (score 0):

the first function in the post has some syntax errors. Here is an example for a `sum()` function that returns the sum of its arguments, where the second argument has a default value of 4:

```
const sum = (a: number, b: number = 4) => {
  return a+b
}

console.log(sum(10))
```